# Rails 3 - routing and parameterized name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, parameterized

I use this rule in my model:

```
  def to_param
    "#{self.name.parameterize}"
  end
```

and in my helper:

```
  def articles_menu
    menu = '<ul>'
    Article.all.each do |article|
      menu += '<li>'
        menu += link_to "#{article.name}", article
      menu += '</li>'
    end
    menu += '</ul>'
    return menu.html_safe
  end
```

but when I'll go to the `/articles/my-new-flat`, I'll get the error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show

Couldn't find Article with id=my-new-flat
```

Missing I something else yet or is any problem in my app? I though for parameterizing of the  name is needed only set up in the model the rule...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FriendlyId gem it has all what you need, here is the link https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/README.md

Problem with your code is that rails under the hub is trying to query your model by "id" attribute, it is not querying "name" attribute. FriendlyId gem patches this for models you want

Comment: There is also a way to do it without using **FriendlyId**. I know about this gem, but I would don't like to interfere into DB structure...

Comment: anyhow, you have to change way how rails routing works and what is `:id` route parameter. You can check FriendlyId source code. There are 2 files you want to check https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb and https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb. Second one is actual extension you are looking for and it should extend ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: One more thing, original implementation of that method should wok also, so take care that it responds to actual ID of model. you just need to test it with `Article.find_on(1234)` and `Article.find_one("article-name-or-title")`